# Flutter: How to make stepper UI in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

This is my stepper part code.

I want my top stepper part like my first image But how to do in bottom of my stepper number.And I also want that when i cleck on my save and next button then my next index show.
and I don't know why is showing in bottom coontinue ana cancel button I want to remove this.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:ddlog/ddlog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StepDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const StepDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StepDemoState createState() => _StepDemoState();
}

class _StepDemoState extends State<StepDemo> {
  int _index = 0;
    go(int index) {
    if (index == -1 && _index <= 0) {
      ddlog("it's first Step!");
      return;
    }

   

    setState(() {
      _index += index;
    });
  }
  int current_step = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Stepper(
            steps: lstStep,
            currentStep: current_step,
            type: StepperType.horizontal,
            onStepTapped: (step){
              setState(() {
                current_step=step;
              });
            },
                  
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Step> lstStep = [
    Step(
        title: Text(
          "Shop Details",
          maxLines: 2,
        ),
        
        content: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "First Name"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Last name"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Mobile Number"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Address"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Your Amount"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Category"),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {

                    },
                    child: Text(" Save And Next"),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                 
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        isActive: true),
    Step(
        title: Text(
          "Shop Certification",
          maxLines: 2,
        ),
        content: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "First Name 1"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Last name 1"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email 1"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Mobile Number 1"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Address 1"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Your Amount 1"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Category 1"),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(" Save And Next"),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        isActive: false),
    Step(
        title: Text(
          "Bank Details",
          maxLines: 2,
        ),
        content: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "First Name 2"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Last name 2"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email 2"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Mobile Number 2"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Address 2"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Your Amount 2"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Category 2"),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(" Save And Next"),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                 
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        isActive: false),
    Step(
        title: Text(
          "Shop Image",
          maxLines: 2,
        ),
        content: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "First Name 3"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Last name 3"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email 3"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Mobile Number 3"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Address 3"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Your Amount 3"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Category 3"),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(" Save And Next"),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
              
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        isActive: false),
    Step(
        title: Text(
          "Delivery Details",
          maxLines: 2,
        ),
        content: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "First Name 4"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Last name 4"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email 4"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Mobile Number 4"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Address 4"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Your Amount 4"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Category 4"),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(" Save And Next"),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
               
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        isActive: false),
  ];
}
```

How to make a custom stepper like this.

[image]

I want to make stepper like this and when i Click on save and nect button then my next page will go another page.

but my stepper is becoming like this.
[image]

Comment: Please check this out https://github.com/khadkarajesh/stepper